# How to efficiently implement assign a vector's data to a number of variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

For example

```
void assign(vector<int> const& v, int a, float b)
{
    a = v[0];
    b = (float)v[1];
}
```

Here the value types doesn't need to be same. I want to make a function to assign variable number of variables. I can use variadic function. But I think using parameter pack may be more efficient. How to implement it? Thanks!

Comment: This function doesn't do anything meaningful... did you mean for `a` and `b` to be references?

Comment: Do you need it in C++11, or just used the tag since variadic templates were added in C++11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fold expressions to the rescue!

```
template <typename ...P> void assign(const std::vector<int> &v, P &... params)
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    (void(params = static_cast<P>(v[index++])) , ...);
}
```

If if has to be in C++11, you could use the dummy array trick:

```
template <typename ...P> void assign(const std::vector<int> &v, P &... params)
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    using dummy = int[];
    (void)dummy{0, (void(params = static_cast<P>(v[index++])), 0) ...};
}
```

Comment: @MaxLanghof I guess I should. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know the brevity is enticing. Great answer in any case!

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, fixed.